# How To Show All Custom Post Types In A Category Instead Of Pagination?

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, navigation

I want to adjust or edit below codes to show all custom post types without showing page numbers. I just want to show all items in one page. I don't want to keep pagination here. What thing I need to edit or add in this below codes?

```
// show all active coupons for this store and setup pagination
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged
) );
```

Comment: @shibam...remove the 'paged' => $paged from query. For more info check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as below.

```
// show all active coupons for this store and setup pagination
 query_posts( array(
              'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
              'post_status' => 'publish',
               APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
              'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
              'posts_per_page'=>-1
              ) 
           );
```

Comment: Bro, It's perfectly working, Thank you so much for sharing this code with me. Thanks Again. You made me happy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code:

```
// show all active coupons for this store and setup pagination 
   query_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 'post_status' => 'publish', APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1) );
```

remove the line:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

and

```
'paged' => $paged
```

from query_posts().

Comment: Not working in my site.